# How to show number of records along with jquery ui tabs name as a letter shape with counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am working in an application which has 3 tabs.Each tab contains a gridview with some records.I want to show the number of records in the gridview as a letter shape with counter showing the total number of records in it.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#divLog">Log</a></li>
       <li><a href="#divOpen">Openned</a></li>
       <li><a href="#divResolve">Resolved</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to show the result as

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#divLog">Log (2)</a></li>
       <li><a href="#divOpen">Openned (23)</a></li>
       <li><a href="#divResolve">Resolved (5)</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with a letter shape (just like in a mobile message) with counter showing total number of rows in the gridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its logical, You need to call [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) like,

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:'your url from where your get json',//must return json object
       dataType:'json',// use json data type
       success:function(d){
          $('#a-log span').text('('+d.log+')');
          $('#a-open span').text('('+d.open+')');
          $('#a-resolve span').text('('+d.resolve+')');
       }
    });
});
```

Note, you have to return `json` from your `server script` like,

```
{"log":"2","open":"23","resolve":"5"}
```

Add `id` and `span element` in your `anchor tags` like,

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="a-log" href="#divLog">Log <span></span></a></li>
    <li><a id="a-open" href="#divOpen">Openned <span></span></a></li>
    <li><a id="a-resolve" href="#divResolve">Resolved <span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```